# I want to register a model on my django admin and i got this error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, tensorflow, django-models

Here is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Destination

admin.site.register(Destination)
```

Comment: are you working in virtual environment?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. SInce many of us can't read a jpg, could you please post the salient portion of the error? I'm reading the last line as: TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

```
project_folder/venv/Scripts/activate.bat

pip install <package_name>
```

You're working in a global env (C drive). You should change venv or reinstall packages.

Comment: and how do i do that i just started codding still a beginner if possible is they a way i can give you access to the code so you can help me out

Comment: Yes, why not. Use my GitHub in profile to add contributor to your repo [GitHub for begginers](https://product.hubspot.com/blog/git-and-github-tutorial-for-beginners)

Comment: this is the link to my code on github can you work on it https://github.com/UltimatePython/Python-Model

Comment: File "C:\Users\Ni~CODES\Desktop\website\travello\admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    admin.site.register(Destination)
  File "C:\Users\Ni~CODES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-3.0rc1-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 103, in register
    for model in model_or_iterable:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable